# How to apply the style of one set of data to another set of data?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, style

I have a data set that must be plotted using BarChart, and I would like to format the color based on another dataset's style.  For Example:

```
dataColor = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    data = Abs@dataColor;  
styleddata = 
 Style[#, 
    Piecewise[{{Red, # <= threshold}, {Blue, 
       threshold < # <= 1.1 threshold}}, Yellow]] & /@ dataColor;
```

The dataColor variable has the Style information I would like to use to style the next variable "data".  How can I apply the style from the first variable to the second?
[image]

Which produces the Graph Above.   But I want to use the color data that was produced by the threshold of the first dataset to apply to the second variable named data that has all positive values.  So the bars are only positive but colored the same as the order in the first styledata bars.

This is a small example of very large datasets that I need to have formatted for plotting.  So to summarize: The Style is applied to one dataset, based on its values.   Then extracted for use on the main dataset for plotting.  The main dataset has all positive values and the dataset for formatting includes both Positive and Negative values.

Comment: Can you provide your desired output? I'm having trouble interpreting your explanation.

Comment: You are going to get people confused if you use Dataset to NOT mean the Wolfram Language symbol Dataset.

Comment: The question is not clear. Data does not come with a style; it is just numbers or strings/tokens. Styles are applied for display purposes and a style can be applied to different data (with the same configuration) as many times as needed.

Comment: @ Syed  You said:"Data does not come with a style; it is just numbers or strings/tokens. "   I show how the data is formatted in the question.  styleddata = 
 Style[#, 
    Piecewise[{{Red, # <= threshold}, {Blue, 
       threshold < # <= 1.1 threshold}}, Yellow]] & /@ dataColor;  Did you miss that when you voted to close?

Comment: What's `threshold`? Also don't see why it's so hard to show a barchart that looks like what you want. If it is too hard, then I think I don't understand. — Anyway: `BarChart@MapThread[
  Function[{datum, styledatum},
   Style[datum,
    Piecewise[{{Red, styledatum <= threshold}, {Blue, 
       threshold < styledatum <= 1.1 threshold}}, Yellow]]
   ],
  {data, dataColor}
  ]`?

Comment: Threshold is the variable to divide the positive and negative value Styles. but this is a closed thread, so refer to the new question.  Had this not been closed I'm sure there would have been some very good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this works for you, but this is how I'm interpreting your question...

First thing to know is that BarChart can plot multiple sets of data simultaneously, and it might be easier to split out the styles if you split out the data. You can split your dataColor like this:

```
splitDataColor = SplitBy[dataColor, Sign]
(* {{-5, -4, -3, -2, -1}, {0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```

You can use Abs as previously:

```
splitData = Abs@splitDataColor
(* {{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {0}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```

Now we want to match up each data group with your styles, which I think are just Red, Blue, and Yellow:

```
styledData = Thread[Style[splitData, {Red, Blue, Yellow}]]
(* {Style[{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], Style[{0}, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], Style[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, RGBColor[1, 1, 0]]} *)
```

Now just apply BarChart:

```
BarChart[styledData]
```

[image]