# How can the Style of one dataset be applied to another data set for plotting

Tags: plotting, style

I have a data set that must be plotted using BarChart, and I would like to format the color based on another dataset's style.  For Example:

```
dataColor = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    data = Abs@dataColor;  
styleddata = 
 Style[#, 
    Piecewise[{{Red, # <= threshold}, {Blue, 
       threshold < # <= 1.1 threshold}}, Yellow]] & /@ dataColor;
```

The dataColor variable has the Style information I would like to use to style the next variable "data".  How can I apply the style from the first variable to the second?
[image]

Which produces the Graph Above.   But I want to use the color data that was produced by the threshold of the first dataset to apply to the second variable named data that has all positive values.  So the bars are only positive but colored the same as the order in the first styledata bars.

This is a small example of very large datasets that I need to have formatted for plotting.  So to summarize: The Style is applied to one dataset, based on its values.   Then extracted for use on the main dataset for plotting.  The main dataset has all positive values and the dataset for formatting includes both Positive and Negative values.

Comment: This is word-for-word identical to [your previous question on the same topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269901/27951), which was answered, and closed because it was not clear. Particularly in light of the existing answer, you should clarify what was not satisfactory in that answer, and what exactly you need instead. It's not particularly good form to just re-posted a previously closed question.

Comment: In particular, the answer by lericr to your previous question is similar to what I would have proposed as well, according to my understanding of your question. So what is wrong with that answer, and how would you like it fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply the style of one set of data to another set of data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269901/how-to-apply-the-style-of-one-set-of-data-to-another-set-of-data)

Comment: @MarcoB It is not Word for word before it was closed,  it it word for word after I edited it and tried to get it opened again.  After waiting a Day I chose instead to repost thee edited question. I'm amazed by the callous response this question has garnered.  I Downvoted and closed right away then downvoted after I edited and repost.  Downvoted again...Seriously not what this community is about.  If the previous answer was correct I would have accepted it. Do we downvote because I did not comment on an answer from a closed thread?

Comment: I suppose it can feel callous, but the downvoting/closing process isn't intended as a slap in the face. It's more of a hygiene issue. If a post is not adding value to the site, closing it is a way to indicate that. If you would add comments to your original post, you might be able to get it re-opened.

Comment: You have not indicated why the answer is insufficient, so I'm struggling to understand why you think you'll get better results by just re-posting the same thing. It seems clear that the community doesn't understand what you want. Closing duplicates is an example of the hygiene I mentioned, so it's very likely that this new post will also be closed. Closed posts can be re-opened if they are improved.

Comment: This seems like a particularly low-quality question for someone who has been a member of this community for over ten years.  Random capital words which don't align with Wolfram Language syntax, using vague undefined terms, etc.

Comment: @lericr  There is no benifit to this community to have anyone mark, comment, or continue working on a closed thread.  I have done everything needed to reformat and rephraise this question so that an answer will benifit this community.  This is not a duplicate post, as mentioned above.  It was edited and attempted to reopen.  Reposted after a full day.  Hygiene is needed, but it is detrimental to this community when threads are closed and never reopened after all edits have been made.  Then downvoted when reposted. That does not serve anyone here at this forum.

Comment: @chuy Should our process then be to have each question reviewed for "Quality" prior to allowing it to stay in this forum? How exactly should a user interpret that metric?

Comment: Twice this morning users have suggested the answer to a closed thread, and twice I have said no.  Not because the answer was incorrect, but because the thread was closed for lack of detail in the question.   Closed questions are not searchable, and not helpful to this community.

Comment: When you're looking for free help, putting in a minimum amount of effort into the question is usually a good place to start.

Comment: Well, this one is open for the moment. Please clarify what you want. I.e. why is the given answer not correct?

Comment: @chuy  Conjecture and opinion are not helpful to this or any other thread.  Do you have a metric that you use for "minimum amount of effort"?  If so I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I can think of many contexts where conjecture and opinion are appropriate and valuable!

Comment: It’s rich that you want these things quantified when you won’t even supply expected output for your question.

Comment: @lericr The second sentence under the graph covers your comment well.   Please read that.

Comment: I apologize for using jargon without establishing a shared context. The term "expected output" is a term of art in software testing, and I think is generally recognized among the software development community. It means an exact representation one could use in, say, an assertion of equality. One can directly compare generated output with expected output to determine correctness.

Comment: The plot you posted seems close to an expected output, and your text indicated that the only change needed was to have all bars positive. The answer you eventually accepted, however, does not match that description. I think you might try sympathizing with those of us who were confused.

Comment: @lericr The problem I see with the actions and comments taken here is that they take no consideration for the users of this site. Which of course is the reason people should come here.  Users come to get answers to questions.  If something requires clarification request that.  Downvotes and quick closings are elitism. There is no place on this site for that...if the goal is to provide help.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you had a bad experience. My experience was that you never responded to the comments requesting clarification and you never explained what was wrong with my answer. I'm sure we're all doing the best that we can. However unintentional, your chosen interaction style violated the expected decorum for this site. Let's all just chalk this all up as a learning experience.

Comment: @lericr  If you're referring to the closed thread.  I will acknowledge that comments came in on Sunday and by Sunday Afternoon the thread was closed.  If that's not responding fast enough, the moderators here must remember people have lives.   Sunday my Aunt died of a heart attack. In light of my "late"  response...Could the close have waited a bit?  Maybe 24 hours for a reasonable time to respond?  Could people have been more understanding?  I say absolutely yes.  Give the  OP the benefit of the doubt.   A minimum level of courtesy and rules in that regard are absolutely needed here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to provide a potential solution so OP can clarify whether this is acceptable or if there are further requirements:

Here is your data:

```
dataColor = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
data = Abs@dataColor;
```

Let's chose an arbitrary threshold value and get a list of colors, base on the value of the `threshold` and `dataColor`:

```
threshold = 2;
colors = 
  Piecewise[
    {{Red, # <= threshold}, 
     {Blue, threshold < # <= 1.1 threshold}},
    Yellow]& /@ dataColor;
```

Then we can use these `colors` to style the dependent dataset `data`, and chart the result:

```
BarChart@ MapThread[Style[#1, #2]&, {data, colors}]
```

[image: barchart where data is styled according to colorData and the threshold]

Comment: This was a very good solution.  I hope this thread remains open so the answer can benefit the community.